# Finding each chunk of data passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to find the chunk of data passed?.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('notes.txt');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
readStream
  .on('data', function (chunk) {
    hash.update(chunk);
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
  });
```

The `data` event is fired on the `readable` stream for `each chunk of data`, **Is there a way i can figure out what is that each chunk of data is passed?.**

Below is my `sample` text file.

```
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Each chunk is presented in the `.on('data', ...)` handler.  That's where you have to see each chunk unless you store them away to look at them later.

Comment: @jfriend00: for me when i try to see each chunk, it throws me the entire buffer [<Buffer 6f 6e 65 0d 0a 74 77 6f 0d 0a 74 68 72 65 65 0d 0a 66 6f 75 72>]. Streams loads chunk of data.. i want to know what is that chunk of data being passed each time until the file is completely parsed.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Each chunk is presented in the .on('data', ...) handler. => What is each chunk in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is no string decoder, so streams work with Buffers (unless in object mode of course). You can convert a Buffer to a string via `.toString()` to see the string representation of the chunk. However that may not always display correctly because of how utf8 (the default encoding for `.toString()`) is designed (e.g. some characters span more than one byte, so a chunk could end on a partial character). Example of `.toString()`:

```
readStream
  .on('data', function (chunk) {
    hash.update(chunk);
    console.log(chunk.toString());
  })
```

Comment: The data is recieved as chunk. I want to know what amount of chunk is passed each time.

Comment: The chunk size? Just use `chunk.length` to get that information.

Comment: The reason you see the entire file in the chunk is because the `fs.ReadStream` uses a [`highWaterMark` of 64KB](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/523929c9272a53c9429616564a45f2af59670e47/lib/fs.js#L1462). Your file is much smaller than this, so the whole file is read into the internal buffer at once. This in turn leads to just one `data` event, with the contents of `chunk` being the internal buffer. If you had a file larger than the size of the default `highWaterMark`, you would see multiple chunks.